# Add usb to ethernet support to tablet Teclast t20

Tags: usb

i would like to allow my tablet Teclast T20 to connect to ETHERNET via USB.

I already own a USB to ETHERNET ADAPTER, that i use succesfully with my windows 10 laptop.

It is an ASIX AX88772 USB2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter, and i found that for this adapter is available a driver (source) in ASIX website

[ASIX AX88772 USB2.0 to Fast Ethernet Adapter Drivers](https://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=86;71;101&PLine=71)

that should work for Linux and Android.

But when i connect the adapter to my tablet using an OTG Usb to microusb cable, and connect the ethernet cable to the adapter, nothing happens.

Searching on the web, i found that with Teclast T10, that is and older version of my tablet (that was without 3G module), was possible to connect to ethernet via a similar adapter with same chipset as mine : UtechSmart USB 2.0 to 10/100 Ethernet Network Adapter (Model US-USB2-E100).
Take a look here (min 5:55)
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIKpsqEMvHs)

My tablet Teclast T20 has cpu MT6797X (X27) and runs on Android Nougat 7.1 and has connectivity WiFi + LTE 
The Teclast T10, instead, has cpu MT8176 and runs on Android Nougat 7.0 and has only WiFi connectivity

So perhaps the kernel is different and the drivers pre-built in the kernel are different.
How can i check if an USB to Ethernet driver is already built in the kernel of my tablet?
And, if it is not available, how can i add the driver to my tablet? I know that i should have the sources of my kernel, but i think it will be difficult to get them from Teclast.
Any suggestion?

Thank you!
Lodovico.

Comment: Usually you should see in the kernel messages (`dmesg`) when you plug in the USB Ethernet adapter if it has been loaded correctly. The main problem is that usually you would execute the dmesg command via ADB/USB but the port is required for the Ethernet adapter. Therefore I would try to use ADB over Wifi to establish an adb connection that does not block the USB port. Then connect the USB Ethernet adapter and check the dmesg messages. I did this just for testing and was able even to see the link up/down messages.

Comment: Thank you for the information. What i can say for now, is that installing an app 'Usb device info' i can see that the adapter is recognized when i connect it (because the app shows correct informations about brand (Asix) and model).

Comment: The problem is that the leds are not blinking and there is not data connection...

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)